# How to put Spring Boot logging data into database? I want to put all INFO and ERROR messages to database

Tags: java, spring, logging, model-view-controller, spring-boot

So i am creating admin panel for application and i would like to put all user problems and user actions to database so i could show them in admin panel. That way admins would not have to go and check logging files which contains alot of other info they do not need to use. Yet i also need logging file for myself so i could see if something happens with server.

What is best way to do this, how to setup that kind of logging globally so i would not have to put them to database manually in each controller?

Comment: Please specify which logging framework you use. For Log4j and Logback there are appenders which write to database. Which makes it just a matter of configuration.

Comment: I will be using Log4j2

Comment: How about reading the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender) which explains how to configure a JDBC based appender. (Which is provided out-of-the-box).

Answer (score 4):

You can use special database appender (org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender) here is the explanation link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm

or you can create your own logger by extending already existent librery such as Log4J
something like this

```
public class MyLogger extends Logger {

    protected MyLogger(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void info(Object message) {
        super.info(message);
        db.save(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: No you don't it is just an example not real implementation .Listen it is a bad practice to create your own Logger unless there is some very special case (and saving logs in database is not special :)). In your situation your better off with using special appender that log4j has. I suggest you read some stuff on how to use logging  here is simple tutorial http://www.journaldev.com/7128/log4j2-example-tutorial-configuration-levels-appenders  you can start from here and walk your way up to link i gave you in the answer .

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot includes by default SLF4J: logging facade and Logback: SLF4J implementation

So in application.properties , we can specify properties for console or file output

As you need to log into Database , you can create Logback specific file i.e. logback.xml and specify required configuration of appender in it and Boot will pick that

http://dev.cs.ovgu.de/java/logback/manual/appenders.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

In case you want to use log4j,you have to exclude default logging and include log4j

Then configure pom.xml as shown below and do further configuration as per log4j

```
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
     </dependency>
```

Creating Appenders in log4j :

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

http://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/how-to-create-logs-in-database-using-jdbcappender-in-log4j/